# How can I improve playing Rumble against Yorick?

Tags: league-of-legends

Yorick's Ghosts keep harassing me and I cannot even farm under the turret! When he gets his Tear of the Goddess, he's unstoppable because he can turret dive with his ultimate whenever he wants, and I can't do a thing.

I tried asking for a jungler gank, but Yorick is tough and he can always escape 
from the ganks.

What should I do when I'm Rumble?

Answer (score 6):

First of all, recognize that this is not a favorable matchup.  You aren't going to harass him out of lane.  Unless the Yorick makes a terrible mistake, he's not going to be low enough for you to burst either.  With that in mind, you "win" this match up by coming out of the lane with equal or better farm.  Don't take needless harass trying to hit Yorick with your flamethrower, etc.

Second, pay attention to Yorick's items.  If he rushes Manume immediately after his tear, he's going offensive and will probably be trying to kill you. so play extra defensive.  You may even be able to bait Yorick into over committing while your jungle is near by, creating a gank oppurtunity.  If Yorick comes back with Spirit Shroud, he's building tankier.  This means that he's going to do significantly less damage.  With the sustain from a hextech revolver, you should be able to free farm.

Third, Yorick's meaningful damage is AD.  However, he's not going to be getting any armor pen items and probably didn't rune for armor pen either.  Some armor items like Ninja Tavi's will significantly reduce the damage that Yorick is doing to you.

Finally, the biggest way to solve this issue IS jungle ganks.  Junglers don't always know when you're countered in lane though.  If you are up against Yorick, as for a gank EARLY.  Be polite and friendly.  Explain that once Yorick hit's 6, the gank is much harder.  A lvl 2 gank would be best but even a lvl 4 gank after a full jungle clear can do wonders against Yorick.  If you get one that early, he probably won't have been back to buy a ward.

Comment: Meh Just played a ranked game. And get counter pick'd again with Yorick , This Guide is really useful! But should I get some MR too? Cause Yorick's Ghosts also deal magic damage , and it hurts me

Comment: Rumble isn't the strongest top laner to begin with.  If you start out ahead, he can snowball, but he's got a lot of counters too.  You might want to think about investing in some other tops, if that's your preferred lane.  Yorick, Teemo, Riven, Vlad cover all your bases.

Answer (score 5):

You might have to ask from help from your jungle to get the upper hand on him.  If you can gank him and gain levels and gold on Yorick, you should be able to negate his harass.

However as Rumble, your harassing abilities are not as good as Yoricks.  Rumble is intended to chase and disrupt enemies having medium tanking ability and damage.

Item choice is a key here, start with a cloth armor and 5 health potions.  He's going to harass you and there's nothing you can do about it.  You need to stay in the game by healing and getting cs.

Runes and Masteries can be tricky.  You probably want 9/21/0 so late game you can be an off tank and for Yorick, help you survive until jungle or top can gank.  Pick any runes that fit your play style. I would prefer AP/HP/CD etc against Yorick.

For your summoners abilities, teleport is a great option as if he does get the upper hand early, you can shop and be back quickly.  Then I would recommend either ignite or exhaust.  If you are being pushed by him, exhaust is going to help if he tries to dive you and when your jungle comes.

This is a basic guide, you may have to tweak this for your play style and skill.  This is a good starting point for your hard counter.

Answer (score 0):

There are some champions that can't really do anything against Yorick, so don't play Rumble against Yorick, it's not like you HAVE to play Rumble against him. With that said, use the bushes, the ghosts wont follow you into the bushes, so it's easy to lose them.

But my number 1 tip is, play Cho Gath since he can actually lane versus Yorick, but no one wins versus him.

Answer (score 0):

This is a losing lane for Rumble, but with some jungler help you should be able to even out the lane some. Remember to use the brush to de-aggro his ghouls, harass him with your flamespitter and harpoons whenever you can, and try not to go too crazy without your jungler's help.

Answer (score 0):

Some match ups are just in another champs favor, yorick is just a great pick vs rumble.

Best bet is to try stop him pushing you to hard so you can at least stay in range of the bushes and use them to lose aggro from the ghouls and try and harass him early before he gets chalice/tear as you have the advantage of no mana.

just surviving a yorick lane as rumble is a win

Answer (score 0):

Start cloth 5.  Play safe wait for ganks. You could probably beat him in all in at level 6 with ignite assuming you can get away from his ult afterward.  Either way your ult should be able to get kills in ganks. Early ninja tabi and and hextech revolver.  Take double golems if you're getting zoned.  Mostly you should communicate with your jungler/mid to shut him down.   Try and help mid if you cant do anything top.  Remember you're teamfight is much stronger than  Yorick's so i your behind its okay coming into mid.  Also Rumble can clear jungle fast for farm mid game to make up for laning phase.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't play Rumble against him in the first place. If you get counterpicked or you play blind pick, you have several options:

1. Go 9 21 0 (if you dont do that usually)
2. Realize that Yorick does 90% Physical DMG (his ghoul "spawns" do magic dmg, but the main dmg are the ghouls AAs and these are physical)
3. Start Cloth 5 or start Boots 3pots and wait for the 4th in the base!
4. Max your shield (W) first! This is always something you can do as rumble if you are loosing the lane!
5. And finally: Get 1 or 2 Dorans Shields early. This helps you a lot and you can sell them later on. This is also something you can do any time you loose against an AD bruiser top.